# Stripe.validateCardNumber not returning true

Tags: jquery, stripe-payments

I am currently working on a checkout form, using Stripe as the payment gateway. I am using Stripe.js client side validation functions to verify card information input. The problem is that I can't seem to get the functions to return true, even while inputting values that should return true, such as 4242424242424242.

Here is a relevant snippet of code:

```
var error=false;

var cc_number=$('#cc_number').val(),
    cc_exp_month=$('#cc_exp_month').val(),
    cc_exp_year=$('#cc_exp_year').val(),
    cc_cvc=$('#cc_cvc').val();

$('#cc_number_error').hide();
$('#cc_exp_error').hide();
$('#cc_cvc_error').hide();

$('#cc_number').keyup(function(){
    if(!Stripe.validateCardNumber(cc_number)){
        error=true;
        $('#cc_number_error').show();
    }
    else{
        error=false;
        $('#cc_number_error').hide();
    }
    $('.address_f_name').val(error);
});
```

I can always manage to get the validation methods to return false, but never true.

There is definitely a possibility that there is something wrong with my code, as I am a beginner in programming. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are captured `cc_number=$('#cc_number').val()` when creating the event handler. This value is never going to change, and won't reflect the actual value of the form field when your handler is called. Instead of saying:

```
Stripe.validateCardNumber(cc_number)
```

you should say

```
Stripe.validateCardNumber($('#cc_number').val())
```

Comment: That was a big mistake on my part. Thanks!